# JAWS does not list elements using menuitem roles

Tags: html, screen-readers

I'm struggling with trying to build an accessible, valid and semantic navigation with W3C recommendations and JAWS. Job Access With Speech (JAWS) screen reader seems to behave poorly when using the `role` attribute with the `menuitem` value, essentially ignoring it when using JAWS' short-cut keys.

So given the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" role="menuitem">This is a menuitem link</a>
```

or even the more appropriate:

```
<button type="button" role="menuitem">This is a menutiem button</button>
```

Then using `INS` + `F3` and selecting either *links* or *buttons* lists, JAWS will say no links or buttons were found.

Is there a more appropriate way to use roles in combination with navigation and JAWS?

Update: I think I've come to the conclusion it is better to use only a sprinkling of `role` (and `aria-`) attributes when adding accessible features. JAWS seems to interpret semantic code well enough for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

JAWS is not listing your button/link in a buttons/links list because you've *changed* its role to `menuitem`. As per this newly published [Using WAI-ARIA in HTML draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-aria-in-html-20140626/), when you change a role of an element, it gets the new semantical meaning for the assistive technologies.
This said, your link or button is neither a link nor a button for JAWS anymore, but a menuitem. This is the point of ARIA.

Comment: I'm still confused...the link you supplied shows `menuitem` nested within `menubar` with no mention of having to be inside an `application` role. Since my goal is to create an menu navigation, it seems to me the encompassing role should be `navigation`, not `application`.

Comment: The thing is that in menus, keyboard navigation is much different from the one on usual web pages. For instance, left/right arrows don't move by character, instead they move between menu items. To do so, you need to free keyboard from JAWS' handling. That's why you have to put the `application` role. Otherwise you can put a menu button (that is, a button that, when clicked, pops up a menu).

Comment: I appreciate the responses, however I think I have to disagree. According to [Marco](http://www.marcozehe.de/2012/02/06/if-you-use-the-wai-aria-role-application-please-do-so-wisely/) (a Mozilla accessibility QA engineer) who says to use `role="application"` very rarely and *not* for menus.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You're right, a `menu` shouldn't be inside an `application` region. But JAWS in your situation is not misbehaving because it's not a button nor a link anymore in its view.